# php / html: replace html closing tags with newlines

Tags: php, html, newline, strip-tags

I am crawling the web for html, and when I use php strip_tags it smushes the entire html into one line removing all structure.

I would like to preserve structure, by replacing closing h, p and br tags with newlines.

Would a preg replace be the best solution for this?

Once I replaced all closing tags I would run a strip tags but this way I would have a basic structure.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$str = 'some html';
$tags = array('</p>','<br />','<br>','<hr />','<hr>','</h1>','</h2>','</h3>','</h4>','</h5>','</h6>');
$str = str_replace($tags,"\n",$str);

// then strip tags
```

Comment: Why loop through the array? You can just pass the array straight to str_replace.

Comment: @liquorvicar good point - I forgot str_replace could do that - see updated

Answer (score 0):

Why not just run it through [tidy](http://us.php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) afterwords to get the structure back?

Comment: I would like to strip all html tags, but keep the basic structure with new lines.

Comment: hi @quickshiftin, I'm interested in how one can use tidy to get the structure back

Comment: @jovialcore just follow that link, there's plenty of explanation in the manual